# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css'

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I want to load a PDF and then copy content from it. I'm using react-pdf for this. I'm able to preview the content but text selection is not working. I read that I need to import

```
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css';
```

But when I'm importing it, I'm getting

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css'
```

My react version is

React-PDF version: ^5.3.2
React version:"^17.0.2",

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css';

function News(props) {

const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    setNumPages(numPages);
};

const goToPrevPage = () =>
    setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1 <= 1 ? 1 : pageNumber - 1);

const goToNextPage = () =>
    setPageNumber(
        pageNumber + 1 >= numPages ? numPages : pageNumber + 1,
    );

return (
    <div>
        <nav>
            <button onClick={goToPrevPage}>Prev</button>
            <button onClick={goToNextPage}>Next</button>
            <p>
                Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
            </p>
        </nav>

        <Document
            file="document.pdf"
            onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
            <Page renderTextLayer={true} renderMode="svg" pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: do you try to install css-loader package ?

Comment: Yes. Installed   
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0"
  }